# How to access files found in a different project?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webapi

I have an asp.net web api solution with different project:

- MyProject.Web -- This has the web api controllers
- MyProject.BusinessLogic -- This project holds the business logic and has a folder with .txt files

Since the .Web project has the controllers and is the main executing project, When I try the below codes, it only returns the path to: "//MyProject.Web/bin/..."

```
Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location)!, @"Data\Names.txt")
```

Is it possible to access the path of files in another project? I do not want to use the full path - e.g C:/.../..., But I only need to access it via simple path "ProjectName/folderName/file.txt"

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Server.MapPath](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httpserverutility.mappath) for this. For example

```
string filePath = Server.MapPath(@"~/Data/Names.txt");
```

`Server.MapPath` returns the physical file path that corresponds to the specified virtual path.